# Pandas formatting (adding ':' to output)

Tags: pandas

I have an output that current outputs like this:
h1 h2
a1 5
a2 4
a3 3

However, I need the output to look like this:
a1:5
a2:4
a3:3

I honestly not sure what to use to format it to this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this,

Set up the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'h1' : ['a1','a2','a3'], 'h2' : ['5','4','3']})
```

Join the two columns

```
df['h3'] = df[['h1', 'h2']].apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x), axis=1)
```

You get this output

[image]

**EDIT** extending this example

**Join any number of columns**

For any *number of columns* remove the specific reference to columns

```
df['h3'] = df.apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x), axis=1)
```

This will join all the values in the columns

**Convert numbers to String**

To allow the join to work, convert integers to string thusly

```
df['h2'] = df['h2'].apply(str)
```

We see in this extended example

Create the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'h1' : ['a1','a2','a3'], 
                    'h2' : [5,4,3],
                    'hx' : ['X','Y','Z'], 
                    'hy' : ['A','B','C'] })
```

Note column h2 is now an integer

convert h2 to string

```
df['h2'] = df['h2'].apply(str)
```

Apply the join

```
df['h3'] = df.apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x), axis=1)
```

produces the following

[image]

Comment: I have more than just 3 values though (hundreds of values). Is there a way to setup the dataframe for that many?

Comment: hey @asey20 see the edit, you'll see the specific reference to the columns in the dataframe  has been dropped

Comment: That makes it output like this:
a:1:::5
a:2:::4
etc
Edit: I have to do str(x) which messes it up because the numbers are not strings but integers and joins dont work for ints

Comment: I just df.applymap(str) and then did the expression. Seems to have worked.

Comment: OIC, my apologies, I assumed the numerical values were strings as they were being combined. I've edited to include converting to h2 to string.

Comment: nice one @asey20, df.applymap(str) converts everything in the data frame to a string

Comment: Yup I ended up converting with df.applymap(str). Thank you for the help guys. It is well formatted now.